# Cartesian product with a nonmeasurable set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In my analysis class today, we reviewed a proof of Fubini's theorem in the context of the Lebesgue integral. The proof proceeds by proving the statement for functions of increasing "complexity", i.e. characteristic functions $\rightarrow$ real simple functions $\rightarrow$ nonnegative measurable functions and so on.

One particular step in this proof implicitly invokes that the product of a null set and an arbitrary set is not necessarily measurable; this seems believable, but I am struggling to imagine what might be a proper counterexample.

My guess would be some product of a "weird" Vitali set (i.e. one with infinite exterior measure) with another strangely behaving null set (perhaps something dense and/or uncountable). If nothing else, I presume the nonmeasurable set must have infinite exterior measure, as if it didn't one could could presumably contain in it an open set of finite measure, which would have the nonmeasurable/null set product as a subset of the product of that open set and a null set, and thus measure zero by the normal theorems.

I note here that this is certainly an area where my naiveté is showing, so I am content to either hear a counterexample or be told that my thinking here is categorically incorrect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Consider $A={1}$. Then the product of $A$ and any non-measurable set is non-measurable. Does that work?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean notation-wise with $A = 1$; if you're referring to the singleton, then I believe one should be able to construct a Vitali set on $[0,1]$, say $V$, such that its product with $A$ is just a subset of $[0,1] \times \{1\}$, which should presumably be a set of measure zero.  It seems to me this should have that the product is a null set and thus measurable, but I did a quick search and it seems this hinges on the measure space being "complete"; I however have no idea what this really means.

Comment: If you are talking about a complete measure (like Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{2}$) then the product of a null set and an arbitrary set is necessarily measurable; this is because it is  a subset of a set of measure $0$  (viz. $A\times \mathbb R $).

Comment: @geetha290krm What implies this though? Presumably the general theorem is that we have for measurable $E, F$ that $m(E \times F) = m(E)m(F)$, but this seems to be in indeterminate form in the context of some product between a set of infinite exterior measure and a null set.

Comment: In mesaure theory $0$ times $\infty$ is $0$.